# Does coughing make dry cough worse?

Tags: cough

When I was younger I remember someone telling me to try not to cough when I have a dry cough, otherwise it will get worse.  Is this true?

For example, suppose one gets over a cold and then is dry coughing for a few weeks after that.

Comment: I doubt that coughing will make your cough worse and if you don't cough you will get a tickling sensation in your throat that will force you to cough.

Comment: Someone told me not to dry cough because it gets worse, so curious how true that might be.

Comment: The only real concern is pleurisy. The most important question is whether or not the cough is productive, but I'm not interested and answering a question like this unless it's substantiated through research. Not enough effort has been shown that an attempt was made answer the question yourself.